# How to format Django form with UIKit styling

Tags: django, forms, uikit

I am struggling to see a way to style a django form in the style of a uikit horizontal form. UIKit has the styling I want and Django has the validation and templating I want.A way to implement a datepicker too would be useful.

I have tried the plain django form template with .as_p and .as_table. I have also tried to use Meta and widgets but couldn't get that to work. I can't see how I can add the needed uikit tags to each element and add the uk-form-controls div.

template.html

```
<form class="uk-form-horizontal uk-margin-large uk-align-center">
    <div class="uk-margin">
        <label class="uk-form-label" for="form-horizontal-text">Job Title</label>
        <div class="uk-form-controls">
            <input class="uk-input uk-form-width-large" id="form-horizontal-text" type="text" placeholder="Some text...">
        </div>
    </div>
```

forms.py

```
class job_form(forms.Form):
    job_title = forms.CharField(label='Job Title', max_length=50)
    hiring_manager = forms.CharField(label='Hiring Manager', max_length=50)
    job_description = forms.CharField(label='Job Description', max_length=50)
    salary = forms.IntegerField()
    closing_date = forms.DateField()
```

I am expecting to be able to have the uikit form styling with the templating and validation of django forms but am yet to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Django has a variety of ways to override the form behavior and layout. I see you are using `forms.Form` instance. Simply add your classes to the `form` class like:

```
class NiceForm(forms.Form):
    solid_field=forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'uk-form-input'}))
```

Although it is simple, but sluggish, when you want introduce breaking changes to the layout, I would override the template (or render method if you like) to bundle a reusable widget. [Simple example to extract the form to external reusable template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/#s-looping-over-hidden-and-visible-fields) as you can render them manually as HTML like documentation.

Leave the form clean and use templatetag to override classes:

```
# _form_icludes.html

{% for field in form.visible_fields %}
    <fieldset class="uk-fieldset">
        <div class="uk-margin">
            <label class="uk-form-label" for="{{ field.id_for_label }}">{{ field.label }}</label>

              <div class="uk-form-controls">

                {% if field.field.widget.input_type  == 'select' %}
                {{ field | add_css_cls:'uk-select'}}
                {% elif field.field.widget.input_type  == 'option'%}
                {{ field | add_css_cls:'uk-option'}}
                {% elif field.field.widget.input_type  == 'checkbox'%}
                {{ field | add_css_cls:'uk-checkbox'}}
                {% elif field.field.widget.input_type  == 'select'%}
                {{ field | add_css_cls:'uk-select'}}
                {% elif field.field.widget.input_type  == 'file'%}
                {{ field }}

                {% else %}
                {{ field | add_css_cls:'uk-input'}}

                {% endif %}

                {% if field.help_text %}
                    <span class="uk-text-small uk-text-left uk-text-italic">
                     {{ field.help_text }}
                    </span>
                {% endif %}
                {% if field.errors %}
                        {% for error in field.errors %}
                    <p class="uk-flex uk-flex-middle uk-text-danger ">
                        <span data-uk-icon="icon:warning" class="uk-text-danger uk-margin-small-right"></span>
                        {{ error | escape }}
                    <p/>

                </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endif %}

         </div>
   </fieldset>

{% endfor %}
```

```
# add_css_cls

from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def add_css_cls(value, arg):
    css_classes = value.field.widget.attrs.get('class', '').split(' ')
    if css_classes and arg not in css_classes:
        css_classes = '%s %s' % (css_classes, arg)
    return value.as_widget(attrs={'class': css_classes})
```

There are [many different ways](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tag/forms/).